# Use a different timezone for one cron job?

Tags: cron, timezone

I have multiple cron jobs in one crontab (as usual). One of the jobs interacts with a remote system in another timezone, which means I need to adjust the crontab every time either timezone enters or exits daylight savings.

I know I can set `CRON_TZ` to control what timezone cron uses for *all* jobs, but is there a way to set a different timezone for one of many?

Obvious ideas include:

- Have a cron job for updating your crontab.
- Have a separate user with a different default timezone, just for running those TZ-sensitive jobs.

Both of which seem a bit hacky. Are there any nicer solutions out there?

Comment: Is "use something else than crontab" an option? Because other automated time-based execution systems exist for various platforms, and at least the dominant scheduler on modern Linux does support specifying times and dates with time zones per timer. Are you using Linux, if yes which, or some other Unixoid?

Comment: @MarcusMüller probably hard to switch away from cron, but knowing good alternatives would be handy. We're using CentOS 7 (I know, I know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using systemd timers, you can define what would classically be Cron jobs as timers, which race to an `OnCalendar=` specification, which can incorporate time zones.

Regarding the mentioned hurdles switching away from cronjobs: at least the recurring time event specification allows for basically the same functionality; so that's nice for migration. I don't know whether there's a conversion tool that just takes crontab lines and converts them to systemd timer units, but I could very well imagine that existing.

Comment: Thanks! I assume the literal answer to my question then is "no, cron does not support per-job timezones and all the ways to achieve that involve either hacks or a migration"?

Comment: I don't *think* it does, honestly. But I'm not sure what anacron's full feature set is. I'll certainly won't mind if you wait with accepting this answer for a while!